# Does JMS require hsqldb files in jboss 5.x?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jms

I am trying to remove hsqldb files from the jboss server as part of server security. After removing I can't deploy my project while deploying it
 throws queue not bound exception.
Which is normally due to jms queue.
Does JMS queue depends on hsqldb?
If so is there any workaround.

Answer (score 1):

JMS in JBossAS 5.x (and older) uses a DataSource to store messages. By default, this points at the standard hsqldb one that is configured.

If you remove the hsqldb DataSource you will need to either:

- Replace it with your database
- Remove the standard JMS queue & topic configurations

I think you will find that this AS also uses that DataSource for persisting EJB timers.

Comment: Please suggest me how to configure jboss using the above two points. As I want JMS to work.

Comment: Refer to [JBoss Messaging User's Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/docs/guide-1.0.1.SP5/html_single/) and have a look in `$JBOSS_HOME/docs/examples/messaging`